# How to write a value in Ohms with an Omega in a Jupyter MD cell

Tags: python, markdown, cell, jupyter

I would like to have appear an Ω like in

> 87 Ω

in normal text flow
in a jupyter notebook markdown cell.

I can copy/paste and Omega as HTML code out of a browser but that would a bit too clumsy all the time. I'd prefer a programatic solution. Using $$\Omega$$ gives a nice Omega, but escapes into Latex mode and puts it out of the normal text flow.

Comment: You could use the html entity `&#937;`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works. Only not very mnemonic. Next time would be uing it, would I still know that it's &#937;?

Comment: How about `&Omega;`?

Comment: &Omega; is fine but a "scientific" Omega would be even better

Comment: The complete range of choices is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega#Character_encodings), but if you want a scientific omega I think you're going to have to remember the codes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the choices. I believe I now can live with both, either mnemonic or using e.g. ```&#x1D6C0;```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using double $ use single $, e.g.

```
The resistance is $R=1\ \mathsf{k\Omega}$, and...
```